# Laravel slug performance eloquent

Tags: laravel, slug

I have setup a route like this:

```
Route::get('/prod/{id}/{title?}', 'Web\GetItemController@getItem')->where('id', '[0-9]+')->name('prod.item');
```

This is to retrieve a item based on the `id` the `title` is only a optional parameter in order to make the url look somewhat nicer.

Then in the controller I fetch the item like this:

```
class GetItemController extends Controller
{
    public function getItem($id, $title = null)
    {
        $item = new product();
        $data = $item->getProdInfo($id);
        // Show view with data...
    }

}
```

So I should be able to fetch the item with or without the `title` parameter.

So a call like this would trigger the route **"https://www.x.com/prod/3/sonic-free-games"**

But is there any difference in performance using slug like I do above?

`/prod/{id}/{title?}` **vs** `/prod/{id}`

Comment: If there are, its minuscule and as an effect of the framework parsing an extra URL parameter. Try not to worry too much about micro-optimizations. One thing to watch out for is character limit, though.

Comment: @Derek what do you mean by character limit?

Comment: I could never do this topic justice in a single comment, but this answer definitely does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2020002

Comment: @Derek thanks for the link! Guess I dont have to worry about that either since my title never exceeds 40 chars